# express-restify-mongoose query multiple attributes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, express, mongoose

**Problem:**

I am trying to send a query to my nodejs server from angular2 using [`express-restify-mongoose`](https://florianholzapfel.github.io/express-restify-mongoose) that will search through more than 1 attribute.

**What I have (works):**

```
let regex = '{"title":{"$regex":"(' + text + ')"}}';
```

**What I tried/want (doesn't work):**

```
let regex = '{"title":{"$regex":"(' + text + ')"}, "content":{"$regex":"(' + text + ')"}}';
```

In the [documentation](https://florianholzapfel.github.io/express-restify-mongoose/#query) there isn't an example for 2+ attributes.

**Question:**

Is this even possible through a single query? If not how could I best solve this?

**Edit:**
Would also be happy with a solution without that library, but would be best if it still involves a single query.

**2. Edit:**
Here is the full function that I call to get the data (not working example):

```
getPostsQuery(text: string){
    let query = '';
    let limit = 25;
    let headers = new Headers();
    let authHeaders = this.authService.getAuthHeader();
    headers.append(authHeaders.name, authHeaders.value);
    let regex = '{"title":{"$regex":"(' + text + ')"}, "content":{"$regex":"(' + text + ')"}}';

    let populate = [
        {path: "tags"},
        {path: "creator"}
    ];

    query += `&limit=${limit}&query=${regex}`;

    return this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}/post?populate=${JSON.stringify(populate)}${query}`, {headers})
        .map((response: Response) => response.json());
}
```

Comment: What happens with the second query? No data? Error?

Comment: error, invalid query :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use standard query condition/criteria syntax of MongoDB.

Use `$and` or `$or` operator as per your requirement:

```
{ $and: [{"title": {"$regex": "(' + text + ')"}}, {"content": {"$regex": "(' + text + ')"}}] }

{ $or: [{"title": {"$regex": "(' + text + ')"}}, {"content": {"$regex": "(' + text + ')"}}] }
```

Comment: What are the regex strings you are passing?

Comment: I can put this in the URL? see my 2. edit for clarification

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean by *put this in the url*

Comment: I think you are missing a **&** in your query (*between populate & query parameters*). It should be `return this.http.get(\`${this.apiUrl}/post?populate=${JSON.stringify(populate)}&${query}\`, {headers})
        .map((response: Response) => response.json());`

Comment: I figured it out, by using a `JSON` and then `JSON.stringify(object)` it worked.

Answer (score -1):

Try using ES6 template literals to make the string.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: How does it answer/solve the problem stated by the OP?